# abstract method and self variable and NameError

Tags: python, oop, abstract-class, self

I will show you 2 pieces of code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class AbstractEmployee(ABC):
  new_id = 1
  def __init__(self):
    self.id = AbstractEmployee.new_id
    AbstractEmployee.new_id += 1

  @abstractmethod
  def say_id(self):
    pass

# Write your code below
class Employee(AbstractEmployee):
    def say_id(self):
      print('Sim, o ID dele é {}'.format(self.id))

e1 = Employee()
e1.say_id()
```

output: Sim, o ID dele é 1

2nd code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractEmployee(ABC):
  new_id = 1
  def __init__(self):
    self.id = AbstractEmployee.new_id
    AbstractEmployee.new_id += 1

  @abstractmethod
  def say_id(self):
    pass

# Write your code below
class Employee(AbstractEmployee):
    # def say_id(self): do not use say_id
    print('Sim, o ID dele é {}'.format(self.id))

e1 = Employee()
e1.say_id()
```

output: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Why do I get this NameError? I thought since I inherited AbstractEmployee in class Employee, shouldn't I be able to access self.id from AbstractEmployee class? Why I am able
to access it in the first piece of code and print 'Sim, o ID dele é 1'
and not in the 2nd one?

I will add a 3rd piece of code and I still get the same error, eventhough I removed the abstractmethod:

```
class AbstractEmployee:
  new_id = 1
  def __init__(self):
    self.id = AbstractEmployee.new_id
    AbstractEmployee.new_id += 1

  def say_id(self):
    pass

# Write your code below
class Employee(AbstractEmployee):
    # def say_id(self):
  print('Sim, o ID dele é {}'.format(self.id))

e1 = Employee()
e1.say_id()
```

output: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Why do you think `self` is defined anywhere in that class block?

Comment: If the `print()` isn't inside a `say_id()` method definition, then the point in time when it gets called is completely unrelated to when you called `e1.say_id()`.  In fact, it happened *during the definition of the `Employee` class* - no instances of the class can even exist yet, so there's nothing that HAS an id to be printed.

Comment: @jasonharper but since I inherited AbstractEmployee shouldn't it work?

Comment: I just run the 3rd code on Pythontutor and it crashed when Python reads the Employee class: tinyurl.com/ykd35sff

Comment: Inheritance has absolutely nothing to do with this.  The `print()` isn't in a method, therefore it gets called during class definition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, your answer with Bey's threw light on this issue to me. Finally, do you have any reference to understand more about this? I will upvote your comments.

Comment: I think I understood now, self is like a parameter e.g. Employee.say_id(e1) outputs 'Sim, o ID dele é 1' and in the 3rd and 2rd code I didn't define any parameter self, so when python run print() it tried to find self, but it was not defined yet. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second version has an error caught during the parsing of your class definition to bytecode.

In example 2 if you change the code to avoid the reference to self altogether,

```
print('Sim, o ID dele é XX')
```

Then you will get a new error:

`TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Employee with abstract method say_id`

To override an abstract method you need to re-define that method in the subclass.

More generally, there is nothing special about `self` -- Python always feeds methods a reference to the object to which a method belongs. You could call this anything you want. For example:

```py
class NamedPerson:
    def __init__(joker,name):
        joker.name = name

    def get_name(bill):
        print(bill.name)

person = NamedPerson("Carl")
person.get_name()
```

You'll get the output "Carl".

The variable `self` for the first argument of methods is so well adhered to by the Python community that it is easy to mistake it for keyword, such as `this` in Java, which is a keyword that always points to the object it is called from.

You are trying to use `self` like a Java user would use `this` but that is not how Python is designed.

Comment: It definitely is a runtime error, it is not a syntax error, the syntax is perfectly valid python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what I meant was that it's thrown because it is a syntax problem -- you won't even get to 
```e1 = Employee() 
e1.say_id()```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok -- bad usage of "syntax error" -- however, my linter caught it -- I revised to simply point out where it fails w/o trying to classify the error.

Comment: @Bey What puzzled me is that since I inherited the class I must be able access self.id, right? Even if I remove the abstractmethod I still get the same NameError.

Comment: @JoãoVitorGomes no — you only have access to self in the first version because you got it from the first function argument — behind the scenes python always feeds a reference to the object as the first argument — see the later part of my answer

Comment: Do you agree with jasonharper comments? I got kinda confused with your explanation and his

Comment: @JoãoVitorGomes you have two errors in your second version — self isn’t defined and you don’t override the abstract method. Your third version still tries to use self. Again, self is not a keyword — self.id in the __init__ function doesn’t create a generally available variable named self.

Comment: @JoãoVitorGomes I suggest you also read this page https://www.edureka.co/blog/self-in-python/

Comment: I think I understood now, self is like a parameter e.g. Employee.say_id(e1) outputs 'Sim, o ID dele é 1' and in the 3rd and 2rd code I didn't define any parameter self, so when python run print() it tried to find self, but it was not defined yet.

Comment: @JoãoVitorGomes you got it! :-) it’s automatically passed to the first argument in a method — whatever it’s called